# MySQL Prepared Statements Appeding Where Condition Not Working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Here is the actual query

```
select taken_date, DATE_FORMAT(taken_date, '%Y') taken_date_year, count(id) num_of_orders, sum(total_order_days) total_work_days from
(   
    select id, taken_date, getNumOfWorkDaysForOrder(order.order_num) total_order_days from order 
    where order.is_active = 1 and order.deleted_at is null and order.vendor_id = vendor_input  and 
        order.company_id = company_input and order.contact_id = contact_input and order.candidate_id = candidate_input
    order by taken_date 
) as order_years group by YEAR(taken_date) order by taken_date desc;
```

I want to add where condition based on the input if it is not null, tried prepared statements and concatenation to add the where condition to the query but no luck.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE 
  getAllActiveOrdersGroupByTakenDate(vendor_input INT, company_input INT, contact_input INT, candidate_input INT)
BEGIN
    SET @prepareQuery = "select id, taken_date, getNumOfWorkDaysForOrder(order.order_num) total_order_days from order 
        where order.vendor_id = "+ vendor_input +" and order.is_active = 1 and order.deleted_at is null";

    IF company_input IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @prepareQuery = CONCAT(@prepareQuery, ' ', "and order.company_id = "+company_input);
    END IF;
    IF contact_input IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @prepareQuery = CONCAT(@prepareQuery, ' ', "and order.contact_id = "+contact_input);
    END IF;
    IF candidate_input IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @prepareQuery = CONCAT(@prepareQuery, ' ', "and order.candidate_id = "+candidate_input);
    END IF;

    SET @finalQueryPart1 = CONCAT("select taken_date, DATE_FORMAT(taken_date, '%Y') taken_date_year, count(id) num_of_orders, sum(total_order_days) total_work_days from
    (", @prepareQuery);

    SET @finalQuery = CONCAT(@finalQueryPart1, ") as order_years group by YEAR(taken_date) order by taken_date desc");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @finalQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: you had an issue with your CONCAT() syntax before you edited your question.

When you want to append content, you must assign it back to the original string. CONCAT() is a function that returns the concatenated string. It does not have any side-effect of modifying the variable you use as an argument.

WRONG:

```
CONCAT(@prepareQuery, ' ', "and order.company_id=company_input");
```

RIGHT:

```
SET @prepareQuery = CONCAT(@prepareQuery, ' ', "and order.company_id=company_input");
```

Also, I'm not sure if you can reference the procedure input parameters in these expressions.

Frankly, I hardly ever use stored procedures. MySQL's implementation of stored procedures sucks. It's inefficient, doesn't save compiled procedures, there's no debugger, there are no packages, and so on.

Mostly I just execute dynamic SQL from my applications. There you have debugging, code reuse, familiar string manipulation in a familiar language.

I understand that stored procedures are the tradition in Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server communities, but it's really better to avoid stored procedures in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help after changing it to SET, procedure got executed without errors but while calling the procedure it is showing Mysql error.

Comment: Dropped idea of using MySQL procedure instead written logic in application itself